# Local notification stopped appearing?

Tags: ios5, uilocalnotification

I recently did an app for client which includes local notifications. In the original version the notifications were working absolutely fine. But when the client tried to release another version, changed only image and DB resources no change in the code, the notifications stopped working. Right now I've been trying to debug the code but found nothing at all. Everything seems fine but no notifications. Meanwhile if I run the earlier build, it works perfect. Can you please help me out what could be wrong? Thanks very much for your time.

```
NSTimeInterval diffTimeIntervalSinceNow = timeInterval; //time-interval after which notification should appear


    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; //Create the localNotification object
    [localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:diffTimeIntervalSinceNow]]; //Set the date when the alert will be launched using the date adding the time the user selected on the timer
    //[localNotification setRepeatInterval:notificationInterval];

    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Launch"]; //The button's text that launches the application and is shown in the alert
    [localNotification setAlertBody:alertBody]; //Set the message in the notification from the textField's text
    [localNotification setHasAction: YES]; //Set that pushing the button will launch the application
    [localNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1]; //Set the Application Icon Badge Number of the application's icon to the current Application Icon Badge Number plus 1

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification]; //Schedule the notification with the system
    [localNotification release];
```

That's the code I've been using. But that's the exact same code which is working in the earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

I Corrected your Code:-
try this:- in Button action or inside in any Method

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
       NSTimeInterval diffTimeIntervalSinceNow = timeInterval; //time-interval after which notification should appear


            UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; //Create the localNotification object
            [localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:diffTimeIntervalSinceNow]]; //Set the date when the alert will be launched using the date adding the time the user selected on the timer
            //[localNotification setRepeatInterval:notificationInterval];

            [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Launch"]; //The button's text that launches the application and is shown in the alert
            [localNotification setAlertBody:alertBody]; //Set the message in the notification from the textField's text
            [localNotification setHasAction: YES]; //Set that pushing the button will launch the application
            [localNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1]; //Set the Application Icon Badge Number of the application's icon to the current Application Icon Badge Number plus 1


            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification]; //Schedule the notification with the system
            [localNotification release];
```

for this working:- check this method in App delegate getting some event or not

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

}
```

For cancel all notification use this in

Comment: nothing changed. I guess code is ok cuz I compared both classes with 'fileMerge' and there are no differences at all.

Answer (score 0):

May be your client also modify the alertBody, and the new alertBody's length is too long?